# Trouble loading external page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem loading an external page into my div using Javascript. I get a NS_ERROR_FAILURE in the console.

```
 var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
 req.open("GET", 'helpInfo.html', false);
 req.send(null);
 var page = req.responseText;
 document.getElementById("helpInfo").innerHTML = page;
```

Comment: Its because browsers stop cross domain AJAX hits.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to go cross domain. You might want to read [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). TL;DR version: you can't do it. You'll have to use a server side proxy or something like JSONP.

Comment: Does a simple Javascript sollution exsist?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript you can build a Node.js server and route all your calls through that. That will help the XSS problem.